# Left join but maintain values where NULL may result in Microsoft SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

Table A:

```
id names
1   a
2   b
3   c
```

and Table B:

```
id names
1   x
2   y
```

I'd like to perform a left join of Table B on Table A that results in the following table:

```
id names
1   x
2   y
3   c
```

How can I do this in Microsoft SQL?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT a.id, COALESCE(b.name, a.name) AS name
FROM tab1 a
LEFT JOIN tab2 b 
  ON a.id = b.id
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you just want `coalesce()`:

```
select a.id, coalesce(b.name, a.name) as name
from a left join
     b
     on a.id = b.id;
```